Accessing the workflow log-file, while running the workflow, using the snakemake.logging.logger.get_logfile()-method
I'm trying to use the log-file for the whole workflow, whilst the workflow is still running.
Example:
workflow.smk
from snakemake.logging import logger

path_to_log=logger.get_logfile()

rule all:
    input:
        "some_file.txt"

rule test:
    output: "some_file.txt"
    params: path_to_log=path_to_log
    script: "tracking_memory_usage.py"

tracking_memory_usage.py
with open(snakemake.params.path_to_log) as log_file:
    #do_stuff

cmd-execution:
snakemake -s testing_memory_tracking.smk --cores 2 --profile slurm/ --configfile config_file.yaml

I tried printing 'path_to_log' outside any rule, and it prints what I'd expect, i.e. the path to the log of the currently running workflow. When trying to pass the result of the variable to the 'params'-directive, and then access it from the script in the 'script-directive, the value returned in the script is 'None'.
I even tried to make a copy of the result, and then use that instead:
from snakemake.logging import logger
import copy

path_to_log=logger.get_logfile()
copy_of_path=copy.copy(path_to_log)

rule all:
    input:
        "some_file.txt"

rule test:
    output: "some_file.txt"
    params: path_to_log=copy_of_path
    script: "tracking_memory_usage.py"

Can anybody help me understand, why I can't get anything but 'None' in the script, when accessing the 'path_to_log'-value from the 'params'-directive?
I'm using Snakemake v7.18.2

Give this a try:
from snakemake.logging import logger                                                                
                                                                                                    
rule all:                                                                                           
    input:                                                                                          
        "some_file.txt"                                                                             
                                                                                                    
rule test:                                                                                          
    output: "some_file.txt"                                                                         
    params: path_to_log = lambda wc: logger.get_logfile()                                           
    script: "tracking_memory_usage.py"                                                              
                                                                                                    
# Note that this prints None!                                                                     
print("Log file is " + repr(logger.get_logfile()))                                                                            
                                                                                                    
# But we can defer evaluation using the "lambda:" trick above                                       

I must say that I have a strong suspicion whatever you are trying to do here is a bad idea, but as shown above it can be done. I tested the above on Snakemake 8.

Great, thanks! Though, why do you think that it is a bad idea? Is it due to the fact I access the log for the workflow, before the workflow is finished? If so, I found that a little weird myself.
Though, the "test"-rule would be the last rule in the entire workflow, so I don't see, how it is any different from running an external script manually after the workflow has finished. Could you maybe elaborate?
